# Accessing static methods of a class from a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to build a simple class that will store class name in an instance variable based on the provided string, and then call static methods on that  class name, something like this:

```
$obj = new MyObject();
$obj->setClass('myclass');
$obj->callSomeMethod();
```

Now, MyObject would have something like this implemented:

```
class MyObject {
   public function setClass($class) {
        switch($class) {
             case: 'myclass':
                   // stores MyOtherClass in instance variable
                   $this->storeClass = MyOtherClass
        }
   }

   public function callSomeMethod() {
     // retrieve previously set class
     $class =  $this->storeClass;
     $class::staticMethodCall();
   }
}
```

Now this works, static method  is called on the passed class,however I am getting also PHP notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MyOtherClass - assumed 'MyOtherClass'
```

What should I change to get rid of it ?

Comment: `MyOtherClass` is an unknow identifier, try to use `'MyOtherClass'`

Comment: I would consider whether what you're doing is the best solution to the problem you're seeking to solve. This idea looks convoluted, confusing and error prone.